# pinch to zoom on windows mobile 6

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile-6.5, htc-hd2

Need to develop pinch-in pinch-out effect on HTC-HD2 with OS windows mobile 6.5.
Is windows mobile 6.5 support this feature? If so can anyone provide me exposed APIs or sample code or any good links for doing it?

So far I have implemented UI related stuff(zoom in-out using buttons etc) in C# .net using Windows Mobiles 6.5 Gestures. I am also ready to develop pinch to zoom in native(windows mobile SDK 6) if it supports.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a 3rd-party solution, [***SciLor's HD2 / Leo Multitouch .NET CF DLL***](http://www.scilor.com/hd2-leo-dotNetCfMultiTouchDLL.html), earlier, but have not used it myself yet...

Answer (score 0):

Windows Mobile 6.5 does not support Multi-touch input which is required to implement 
the pinch-in / pinch-out effects.

You may try the Windows Mobile 6.5.3 which was recently released with support for capacitive touch screens (required for multi-touch input)

Comment: HTC HD2 has capacitive touch screen, so i guess you'll have to upgrade the OS, if you want to use multi-touch inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found 3rd party [solution](http://www.windowsphoneme.com/?p=386), which looks pretty state forward to implement. So trying with it.